# Excel - Conditional Formatting not working because cell has an existing formula

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

My conditional formatting rules I am using to highlight a row with value = 1 dont seem to be working because there is an existing formula in the cell. So I assume excel is seeing the formula but not the actual value and not highlighting it. Is there a way around this? I tried =$A2=VALUE(1) and it highlighted some rows but no the correct one.

Comment: My guess is that you are using full column reference in the applies to but are refering to the wrong row.  I bet if you put `=$A1=1` it will work.  The other thing to check to see if the formula is returning `"1"` instead of `1` to excel they are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to *Conditional Formatting* -> *Rules to Highlight Cells* -> *Equals*. Then, you enter `1` and select the preferred formatting.

[image: Screenshot of Rule]

I hope that I translated the menu correctly; I use Excel in the German language since it's my mothertongue.

Comment: Welcome, Loki, and thank you for contributing an answer. Could you update edit your post to include a cropped version of your screenshot? As is, it's a bit difficult to read. I embedded it so readers don't need to click through the link, but that also makes it harder to read since the size is constrained by Stack Overflow's layout.